# jQuery: Get the keydown (not keypress) value of any given character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the "keydown" value of any character (i have that character stored in a variable) in **jQuery**. I used `string.CharCodeAt()` function and it is giving me the ASCII value of the character.

E.g. I am doing `",".CharCodeAt(0)` and its giving me 46 (keypress value). Instead, I want the value to be 188(keydown value) which is equal to `event.which` or `event.keyCode`.

This is because `event.key` or `event.char` doesn't work with chrome.

How can I get the same? Please help.

Reagards!
Swad

Answer (score -1):

Well what you're looking for is the keyCode value which is NOT the ASCII value that is getting returned by CharCode. Any simple key-operation function can use e.keyCode to get the value you seek.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/programndial/b6wa4dp6/)

```
$('#testy').on('keydown', function (e) {
    $('#keyCode').val(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: No, I am not using these keydown and keypress events. I am getting character as a function parameter whose keydown value(unicode) I need to get.

Answer (score -1):

event.keyCode as you say returns the actual key pressed value - from what you say, I think you somehow have to store this value in your string - e.g. string="\x7F" etc. You can then retrieve the value later.